# Node.js require a file relative to the root of the package

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, require

In Node.js, is there any way to require file from the same package without using relative paths? For example, here's a snippet of code from [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/tests/lib/rules/accessor-pairs.js).

```js
const rule = require("../../../lib/rules/accessor-pairs"),
    { RuleTester } = require("../../../lib/rule-tester");
```

The fact that we have to walk all the way up the tree `../../../` to get to the root is not only annoying. It's also brittle, because I can't move the code without updating all of dependency references.

Yet somehow Node.js developers seem to have lived with it the past 10 years. I can't find anything in the docs or Stack Overflow that solves this problem other than a third-party dependency called [require-self](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-self). Nor have I been able to find a definitive statement that *using relative paths is the only non-hacky way for a file to require another file in the same module*.

If there's a way to specify a path relative to the package root in ECMAScript Modules (ESM) but not CommonJS (CJS), or vice versa, I would like to know that as well.

To be clear, I don't think there is a solution to the problem. If there is great. Otherwise, I'm looking for confirmation with an authoritative reference.

Comment: In the past I've typically solved this issue using a bundler e.g. [via this config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) in Webpack, or plugins in others. The other issues you mentioned re files moving are typically handled by most IDEs that have Node support tbh.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the package name itself as a "symlink" to the package root.

---

Example - `foo` package imports `bar` script relative to the `foo` package root.

*package.json*

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "foo": "file:./foo"
    }
}
```

*index.js*

```
const foo = require('foo');
console.log(foo.bar);  // prints "hello"
```

*foo/index.js*

```
const bar = require('foo/bar');  // import relative to the package root

module.exports = {
    bar: bar
}
```

*foo/bar.js*

```
module.exports = 'hello';
```

Comment: do you know what the earliest version node is required for this??

Comment: @nntrn I was able to run both `npm install` and `node index.js` under `node@v10.0.0` and `npm@6.14.12` (which is autoselected when using `nvm use 10.0.0`). Older versions failed `npm install` because of missing `foo/package.json` and I didn't dig deeper into this error (e.g. whether it would be sufficient to just add a dummy package.json).

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the same *package* - if you are writing libraries this won't be useful, but if you are writing the "final application" - the thing that actually gets run:

One option:

> If the NODE_PATH environment variable is set to a colon-delimited list of absolute paths, then Node.js will search those paths for modules if they are not found elsewhere.

So you can do any of:

1.

```
export NODE_PATH=.
node app.js
```

2. 

```
NODE_PATH=. node app.js
```

3. 

```
// app.js (or whatever your entry point is) before *any* require() calls
process.env.NODE_PATH = __dirname;
require('module').Module._initPaths();
```

Or, another way:

> The Module object representing the entry script loaded when the Node.js process launched.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_main

So you can just do:

```
const rule = require.main.require("./lib/rules/accessor-pairs")
```

anytime you want it to be relative to the root (assuming that is how you have your project structured).

Answer (score 1):

If you use vscode then you're in luck - !!!! jsconfig.json in project root handles this masterfully for commonjs, es6, amd, umd, etc

> The jsconfig.json file specifies the root files and the options for the features provided by the JavaScript language service.

---

*jsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@rules/*": ["path/to/lib/rules/"]
    }
  }
}
```

and then to use the alias:

```js
const rule = require('@rules/accessor-pairs'),
    { RuleTester } = require('@rules/rule-tester');
```

---

Read more:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig